# Heap dump fails with jemalloc mcllctl

Tags: heap-memory

I have tried to use the following to dump the mem-profile for a demo program: 
export MALLOC_CONF="prof:true,prof_prefix:jeprof.out"

```
int main()
{
     int i;

     for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        malloc(i * 100);
     }

     const char *fileName = "heap_info.out";

     mallctl("prof.dump", NULL, NULL, &fileName, sizeof(const char *));

}
```

This fails with the following errors(no o/p:

: Invalid conf pair: prof:true

: Malformed conf string

Can some on tell me if I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 8):

Use --enable-prof switch when building jemalloc.